# How can I use a gui button to enable disable code in method and also change the button text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/Hierarchy Editor")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<CompareObjects>("CompareObjects");
    }
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.gameObjectFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Original Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabOrgFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Prefab Modified Font Color", CustomHierarchy.prefabModFontColor);
        CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Inactive Color", CustomHierarchy.inActiveColor);

        if(GUILayout.Button("onoff"))
        {
            CustomHierarchy.onoff = !CustomHierarchy.onoff;
        }
    }
}
```

And the CustomHierarchy

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
//Adapted from Unity3DCollege YouTube Video Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdDrY8Mc2lU
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class CustomHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 2);
    public static Color gameObjectFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabOrgFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabModFontColor = Color.white;
    public static Color inActiveColor = new Color(0.01f, 0.4f, 0.25f);
    public static Color containsBoxColliderColor = Color.yellow;
    public static bool onoff;

    static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        if (onoff == true)
        {
            EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
        }
    }

    private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Color fontColor = gameObjectFontColor;
        Color backgroundColor = new Color(.76f, .76f, .76f);
        FontStyle styleFont = FontStyle.Normal;
        var obj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        GameObject gameObj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as GameObject;
        if (Selection.instanceIDs.Contains(instanceID))
        {
            backgroundColor = new Color(0.24f, 0.48f, 0.90f);
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(obj);
            if (gameObj.activeInHierarchy == false)
            {
                backgroundColor = inActiveColor;
            }

            if (gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider>() != null)
            {
                backgroundColor = containsBoxColliderColor;
            }

                if (prefabType == PrefabType.PrefabInstance)
            {
                styleFont = FontStyle.Bold;
                PropertyModification[] prefabMods = PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications(obj);
                foreach (PropertyModification prefabMod in prefabMods)
                {
                    if (prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_Name" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.w" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_RootOrder" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_IsActive")
                    {
                        fontColor = prefabModFontColor;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor) fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
            }
            Rect offsetRect = new Rect(selectionRect.position + offset, selectionRect.size);
            EditorGUI.DrawRect(selectionRect, backgroundColor);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(offsetRect, obj.name, new GUIStyle()
            {
                normal = new GUIStyleState() { textColor = fontColor },
                fontStyle = styleFont
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the button in the CompareObjects script to diecide if to use or not the line in the CustopmHierarchy script at this part :

```
static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        if (onoff == true)
        {
            EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
        }
    }
```

But pressing the button does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (in `CustomHierarchy()`) is only called once (once the custom heirarchy is initialized):

```
    if (onoff == true)
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
    }
```

Essentially `EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI` is an event handler and when you add the function you are effectively telling the application to run `HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI()` everytime the event is triggered. **You only do this once**, therefore trying to check if `onoff` is true will not do anything because the function (`HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI()`) has already been attached to the event handler.

Instead put the `if (onoff)` statement in the actual `HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI()` function:

```
private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
{
    if(onoff){
        ... //Do the stuff you had in this function
    }
}
```

Therefore, it won't actually use the code you want executed.

Comment: Still not working the button does nothing. The idea is to turn on/off the CustomHierarchy. It's  coloring the objects in the hierarchy for example if object in the hierarchy have a boxcollder component attached color the gameobject in the hierarchy in yellow. But I want the button to turn on/off the using of the CustomHierarchy. But it's not working.

Comment: @DanielLip Can you give some images of what is happening. You asked to stop the code and it should work. Place a Print() function to check if the code is still running when you press the button.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. What I wanted to do is to make a button like a toggle switch or maybe to use a gui toggle somehow to enable/disable the CustomHierarchy. It will be better to disable/enable the whole CustomHierarchy script. But this is what I wanted to do just didn't explain it good enough.

Comment: @DanielLip Is it like a close button? Just call window.Close(). You can't toggle a whole static script (not to my knowledge). Also I'm not sure why stopping the draw call doesn't stop renderering the window